# Applying fitted model of input on output time-series in pre-whitening

Tags: self-study, arima, residuals, white-noise

I have two different time series (input time series and output time series)for doing cross correlation. When I fit input time series for pre-whitening, it has good fit for ARIMA(0,1,1). So for pre-whitening the output time series with same model, whether I have to **consider the fit of output time series** while applying the same model of input time series for pre-whitening?
When I fit output time series, it has the parameters ARIMA(2,1,2).